# "More so" or moreso?

Tags: grammaticality

I often find myself using the two words joined together, **moreso**. I'm not sure where I picked up this usage. I'm also not sure that it's necessarily the correct one, as some proofreading tools will flag for not being a correctly-spelled word. Though I have seen it in multiple places when I've been looking for it, even on this site.

Is **moreso** generally accepted as being correct? Would it be correct to use in a serious paper?

Comment: I have never seen it before in my life, and nor is it recognised by Oxford Dictionaries on-line.

Comment: The one-word form "moreso" is covered fairly well in this Grammarist article: http://grammarist.com/usage/moreso/

Comment: @DanBron I have just noticed that the OED recognises ***moreso*** as a US usage, meaning simply 'more so' as in 'all the more so'.

Comment: I read the article that Dan Bron cites; it is undated, but the comments attached to it go back two years, which places the article somewhere near the end of 2012. The usage examples seem to indicate a form that is in considerable flux, both in terms of how it is used and how well accepted it is. That being the case, it is probably best to avoid using it in any formal situation for now, especially if there is a possibility of incurring some form of disapproval as a consequence.

Comment: I would use it at any level of formality, unless I had a particular reason to avoid risking the disapproval of conseratives. Moreso *because* its usage and acceptance are in flux. Fight the power!

Comment: I'm from the States and frequently read scientific literature from around the world. I have never seen *moreso* anywhere, and I hate it. It reads like a word that rhymes with *peso*.

Answer (score 12):

Moreso and more so are both correct, but in different contexts.

Example:

> *Anna's performance was good, but Emma's more so.*

In this example, the "so" in more so relates back to the statement of the quality of Anna's performance.

However,

> *I believed the novel was moreso about oppression than the human spirit.*

In this case, there is no precedent to justify "more so", therefore "moreso" is used instead.

Be aware also that "moreso" is considered less formal than "more so".

Comment: It's true that the phrase *more so*, as conventionally used, does not work in your second example; but this does not imply that it should be spelled differently (or that spelling it differently will improve anything). Note, for example, that *a lot* is still written as two words in a phrase like *a lot bigger* (though some people have indeed tried to write it as *alot*).

Comment: @ruakh There are examples the other way, as well. "I don't want any more to eat." vs "I don't eat anymore." Also consider adverbial "every day" vs. adjectival "everyday."

Comment: @rintaun: Those are not "examples the other way", since "anymore" and "everyday" are both cases where a compound was standardly written open ("I don't eat any more") or at least hyphenated ("an every-day affair") and eventually became closed. Grammarian's answer is asserting that the whole reason some people write "moreso" is that there's *no* history of using "more so" that way.

Comment: Does your second example mean something different with that word "moreso" than it would with the actual word "more"?

Comment: Please add a valid reference to substantiate your claims.

Comment: The logging level of "DEBUG" is similar to "VERBOSE" only moreso. It doesn't work for me as "more so" in this case.

Answer (score 6):

That Grammarist post is completely misleading, not to mention contradictory.

IF "More so strictly means that to a greater degree ...," then the word "more" *is* a crucial element of the sentence:

> Gina is studious, and Eleanor is more so.

The sentence is stating that "Gina is studious," and that "Eleanor is more so." Meaning, while Gina is studious, Eleanor is MORE studious than Gina. Therefore the word MORE, *is* crucial.

You cannot simply replace the word "more" with "less" or "equally" because those two words are in no way equivalent to "more." If you stated that ...
     Gina is studious, and Eleanor is less so.
... you would be stating that Eleanor is LESS studious than Gina, and therefore it is not an equivalent sentence.

The logic behind the Grammarist site post on this topic is baffling, to say the least.

Anyways, in my opinion, while "moreso" is used MORE (not LESS or EQUAL TO) in the US than in other places, it would probably be wise to use the two-word version (more so) than the one-word, just because it is more widely acknowledged. Acceptance is a bit irrelevant considering the differences among many languages around the world.

Comment: I am just going to assume that it was done with a devilish sense of irony and humor, but seeing a post about correct English word usage and grammar where the concluding paragraph begins with the word "Anyways" was quite jarring! I couldn't stop staring at it and forgot to read the rest of the post.

Answer (score 5):

Excerpting [this Grammarist post](http://grammarist.com/usage/moreso):

Though ***more so*** spelled as two words, the one-word ***moreso*** [gained ground](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moreso%2Cmore%20so&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoreso%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20so%3B%2Cc0) despite the [disapproval of usage authorities](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/moreso.html).

*More so* strictly means *that to a greater degree*, and *so* refers to an adjective or adverb used earlier.

E.g.:

> Gina is studious, and Eleanor is more so

In the sentence above, *so* refers to the the adjective *studious*, and is a crucial element of the sentence while *more* is not. Because *more* and *so* function separately, changing *more so* to *moreso* in cases like this is difficult to justify.

Comment: In my opinion, this answer owes too much to the Grammarist post cited elsewhere in this question without giving proper credit.

Comment: @Mustapha "Moreso" is also a proper noun... https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=proper+noun+definition&oq=proper+n&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.2.0l3.3810.7888.0.11775.9.8.0.1.1.0.326.2129.0j1j4j3.8.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..0.8.1875.0.9IP2mvV3OQs#q=%22Juan+Moreso%22

Comment: @tylerharms Problem is, the Oxford English Dictionary is paywalled and can't be properly cited without paying a hefty fee.

Answer (score 3):

This [Grammarphobia article](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2019/10/moreso.html) discusses the etymology of "more so" and "moreso" at length; it's by far the best resource I've found, and it gave me the direction I needed to write this answer out.

As mentioned in other answers, the 3<sup><sub>rd</sub></sup> edition of *Oxford English Dictionary* (which is online-only and requires a hefty fee to fully access) recognizes it as a "chiefly U.S." variant of "more so". Thanks to a [recent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/614955) by [@DjinTonic](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/428602), we now have the full text of the entry:

| more | <sub>(adv.)</sub> |
| --- | --- |
| **I.1.f.** | With ellipsis of the word or sentence modified. Now frequently with anaphoric so (see **so** *adv*. & *conj*. I.4a) in more so (also, chiefly U.S., ***moreso***). (all) the more: the rather, the more so (*as, because*, etc.). |
| **1997** | --- Anyone perceived as being different from society's norms was a potential target—no-one **moreso** than the local wise-woman. `C. Shaw, Scottish Myths & Customs x. 223` |

As of writing, the only reputable & physically published standard dictionary to feature "moreso" as anything other than a misspelling is the 5<sup><sub>th</sub></sup>—and foremost—edition of *Webster's New World College Dictionary*, which labels it as a "disputed spelling". The dictionary [can be borrowed & accessed online](https://archive.org/details/webstersnewworld0000unse_k1f4) from *Internet Archive*. Here's the full text of the entry:

> **more·so** (môr**′**sō′) ***adv.** disputed sp. of* more so

<sup>Houghton Mifflin Harcourt. (2014). moreso. In *Webster's New World College Dictionary* (5th ed., p. 951).</sup>

**In summation**: Because it's in a standard dictionary – even if it is "disputed" – you can kinda get away with it. If people keep using it, it won't be long until it's begrudgingly accepted by your spellchecker.

Comment: You can see most of the [OED's quotations](https://www.oed.com/search/advanced/Quotations?textTermText0=Moreso&textTermOpt0=QuotText) for "moreso" without a subscription.

Comment: An answer with references. Thank you for this, Vopel.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're welcome! Also, you'll be pleased to know that I just updated my answer to incorporate the new information that DjinToxic posted.

Comment: You need to address 'However, it's important to keep in mind that OED Online is a historical dictionary, not a standard dictionary.' OED faithfully adds usage notes pointing out usages that are slang, informal, rare, disputed, archaic, obsolete ... it's recognised as usually being the best available (though neologisms are often picked up / listed more quickly by Wiktionary).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Honestly, I was mostly going off Grammarphobia inferring it's a non-standard dictionary. Since I don't have access to it, I ended up just taking their word for it, considering how helpful & insightful that article was for me. Wikipedia refers to the OED as a "historical dictionary", so I borrowed the term. It occurs to me that this is all beyond the scope of the answer anyway, so I've made another revision where I remove that bit and instead follow up by talking about _physically published_ dictionaries.

Comment: Djintoxic ? I guess I've overstayed my welcome. What a difference a letter makes!

Comment: @DjinTonic Woops.

Comment: A historical dictionary (OED; M-W) merely lists senses and subsenses in the order they can be shown to have appeared over time, in the lexicon. The others attempt to list usages in order of frequency of use. OED is _the_ standard for English dictionaries.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see. It would be nice if _the_ standard wasn't behind a very expensive paywall, but I guess that's just how things are when it comes to academia.

Comment: Where do you live? On-line OED is freely available via many UK libraries.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth USA

Answer (score 2):

**more** (adv.)

> **I.1.f**. With ellipsis of the word or sentence modified. Now frequently with
> anaphoric *so* (see **so** *adv*. & *conj*. I.4a) in more so (also,
> chiefly U.S., ***moreso***). (all) the more: the rather, the more so
> (*as, because*, etc.).
>
> **1997** Anyone perceived as being different from society's norms was a potential target—no-one **moreso** than the local wise-woman.
> C. Shaw, *Scottish Myths & Customs* x. 223
> [OED online]

---

> **moreso** Misused for *more so*. • While it may not be killing trees, it is alienating to be endless pitched to, even *moreso* when they
> have you figured out. Use *more so*. • We still get the best of the
> old standards—even *moreso* in some cases. Use *more so.* •  We have now
> and will have even *moreso* in the future a unity that binds us all as
> one people, one family. Use *more so*. • It's partially because of the
> wacky plots and situations Mike Allred likes to put his characeters
> into ... but *moreso* because the book seems to vary in strength. Use
> *more so*.
>
> Despite the frequency with which some people use *moreso*, it is
> necessarily two words, *more so*, meaning to an even greater degree
> or extent.
> [*Robert Hartwell Fiske's Dictionary of Unendurable English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=T9wUJMvX4i4C&pg=PA278&dq=%22moreso%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje94TCg9SCAxUcEVkFHVXxBxwQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22moreso%22&f=false) (2011)

> "Newfoundlanders need the money much **moreso** than Ontario workers."
> That was from the editorial page of one of our major dailies. "The
> ranges [of examination results] here are very much concentrated
> **moreso**." That was a school teacher; did she mean more concentrated? God knows. This malpractice arose because of
> misunderstanding of a minor grammatical point, where one uses "so" to
> avoid repetition of a long phrase. "The deficit was a heavy burden
> under the Liberals; under the Conservatives it is more so."
> Perfunctorily taught and half-heard, this has produced the unloveable
> **moreso**.
> [Victoria Branden; *In Defence of Plain English: The Decline and Fall of Literacy in Canada*](https://books.google.com/books?id=XVNs011D3uoC&pg=PA26&dq=%22moreso%22%20%22more%20so%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1-a-sitSCAxWoEFkFHTOFDFIQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22moreso%22%20%22more%20so%22&f=false) (1992)

I wonder whether some users of *moreso* have been led astray by the adverb *moreover*. Perhaps more recent usage guides chide *moreso* lessso.

Comment: The way it rolls off the tongue shouldn't be discounted. I see plenty of people spell "at least" as "atleast", but I've never seen anyone spell "at most" as "atmost".

Comment: Over time, using one space less may even save the odd tree. Another answer with references ;)