# OED 3e: 'Etymology' and 'Meaning & use' for "goto"

Tags: etymology

When trying to search for "goto" on [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com) or [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com), it redirects to *go-to*. Often, entries will state that what you were trying to search for is a common misspelling, but that's not the case here.

Now I'm curious if there's anything about *goto* on [oed.com](https://www.oed.com)—behind the paywall—within the *go* or *go-to* entries, similar to how their entry for *more* includes a mention of *moreso*: "[a] 'chiefly U.S.' [variant of *more so*]" [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/614944)

So, if you have an [oed.com](https://www.oed.com) subscription, I'd appreciate their excerpts regarding this – if there even is any.

Comment: I think that solid _goto_ would be listed this side of the paywall if licensed. It's not so listed, and other sources only give the hyphenated form for the noun and adjective.

Comment: Apparently, [usage authorities still disapprove of 'moreso'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211458/more-so-or-moreso).

Comment: I would not omit the hyphen in *a go-to guy* and I don't think many authors would either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking someone to reproduce text from the OED is not what this site is for, and may well be breach of copyright. If the OP has a specific question that might be answered by the OED they should ask the question. If you want to see what a book says, go look in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OED entry is recent. It has only the hyphenated version and has it as an adjective, although I have seen it used as a substantive.

> **1. Originally U.S. Sport. That may be consulted or relied upon; frequently chosen, utilized, or sought out in a particular situation.** Earliest in *go-to guy*.
>
> 1985 Derek is one of my go-to guys—players who want the ball in crucial situations. *United Press International Newswire (Nexis) 4 April*
>
> 2012 Testing Treatments..remains the single go-to book on this topic in my view. *B. Goldacre, Bad Pharma 371*

Pretty obviously, it gives

> Summary
>
> Formed within English, by compounding.
>
> Etymons: go v., to prep.

Hence: The person or thing that I [would] go to.

As a curiosity, OED has "goto" as a 19th century spelling of "Goitre."

If you have seen "goto" recently, it is probably from C programming, in which a **goto** statement is used for altering the normal sequence of program execution by transferring control to some other part of the program.

It could be that the less than literate are confusing these.

Comment: I found a **1973** (non-sports) example: [Very soon, my boss had marked me as the "go-to guy."](https://books.google.com/books?id=-NLZTX0aCGEC&pg=PA377&dq=%22go-to+guy%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz2MCJu6GEAxVQF1kFHQfDDxwQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22go-to%20guy%22&f=false)—Brian Tracy

Comment: @DjinTonic: The book you cite appears to be from 2004, not 1974. See the [publication data here](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=31409699456&dest=usa&ref_=ps_ggl_18382194370&cm_mmc=ggl-_-US_Shopp_Trade0to10-_-product_id=COM9781576753071USED-_-keyword=&gclid=CjwKCAiA2pyuBhBKEiwApLaIOznb7YRfN0Q8ZJQKqYSrCFrKVTeavcmfAp23sXz1ZiJ-gOlFFCgPGRoCzgoQAvD_BwE) for a version of _Goals_ very similar to the one in your Google Books link. The reference on the Google Books page to "Goals for 1973 By Comprehensive Health Planning Council of South Florida" seems unrelated to Tracy's book. ...

Comment: ... An [index of health-related publications compiled by the U.S. Bureau of Health Planning](https://books.google.com/books?id=IAqLUHxIebwC&pg=PA172&dq=%22Goals+for+1973%22+Florida&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT6bHux6GEAxWmJjQIHTUXCu0Q6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Goals%20for%201973%22%20Florida&f=false) includes two entries for "Goals for 1973" published by the Comprehensive Health Planning Council of South Florida in January 1973—one listed at 84 pages and one at 87 pages; the cited instance from Tracy's _Goals_ appears on page 377 of that book.

Comment: @SvenYargs I think you are correct--I was  going by the date shown on the "Find in a Library" link.